# SQL insert with regexp

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle11gr2

I have a table with data in the following format

```
col1  col2
a1    a2;a3;a4
b1    b2
c1    c2;c3
d1    null
...
```

I'm trying to split the strings, get unique combinations of col1/col2 and insert them into tableB. So the expected outcome should look like this:

```
 a1    a2
 a1    a3
 a1    a4
 b1    b2
 c1    c2
 c1    c3
 ...
```

I tried the following query:

```
INSERT INTO tableB (col1, col2) 
SELECT col1, (regexp_substr(col2,'[^;]+', 1, LEVEL)) FROM tableA 
CONNECT BY regexp_substr(col2, '[^;]+', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL;
```

Not sure what's going wrong here but it keeps executing (it actually went on for more than an hour) and when I finally cancel the task, nothing's been inserted. The table is quite large (around 25000 rows) but I've done similar inserts with larger tables and they worked fine.

I also tried adding a where clause (although it seems redundant) with

```
WHERE col2 LIKE'%;%'
```

That didn't help either.
Any suggestions would be great.

Edit: I tried counting the max number of substrings in col2, to ballpark the number of rows to be inserted, and found the max to be 42 substrings. The whole table has 25814 rows, so worst case scenario, it's inserting 1084104 rows. If that has anything to do with it.

Comment: have you tried using `distinct` as the query you have would produce duplicates?

Comment: Yes I did, even though it didn't make much sense, but it just did the exact same thing. Wouldn't the duplicates be prevented by ' IS NOT NULL' in the connect by?

Comment: could it be trying to produce every combination of col1/col2? it could be why it executes 'forever' and doesn't give any errors, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use connect by to split string into rows.

Use a PL/SQL procedure that does varchar2 -> collection split.

For a ad-hoc kind of query, stick with `xmltable` as a simple way to split string into rows (it is a bit slower than PL/SQL).

The following kind of query is expected to take 3-4 seconds for each input 1000 rows.

```
select t.col1, c2.val
  from (
    select 'a1' col1, 'a2;a3;a4' col2 from dual union all
    select 'b1', 'b2'  from dual union all
    select 'c1', 'c2;c3' from dual union all
    select 'd1', null from dual
   ) t
    , xmltable('$WTF' passing
         xmlquery(('"'||replace(replace(t.col2,'"','""'),';','","')||'"')
                  returning sequence
         ) as wtf
         columns val varchar2(4000) path '.'
      )(+) c2
```

Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb7d/5059

Comment: Thanks that works too. Although like you said , it is a bit slow

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can try is to select all the `distinct` values.

```
INSERT INTO tableB (col1, col2)
SELECT distinct col1, (regexp_substr(col2,'[^;]+', 1, LEVEL))
FROM tableA 
CONNECT BY regexp_substr(col2, '[^;]+', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL;

commit;
```

You should also `commit` the transaction if you need the changes to be permanent.

Comment: This didn't work either give me an ORA-00928: missing SELECT keyword

Comment: modified it slightly. try this.

Comment: No that didn't work I appreciate your answer, but could you maybe explain what you think is wrong instead of giving me code?

Comment: i don't see a problem with the query except for the duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

While I still don't really understand what was wrong with the initial query, I found a work around. The column with the strings I'm trying to split is `participantcountries` and the `p_id` contains unique identifiers.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE split_countries IS

CURSOR get_rows IS
SELECT p_id, participantcountries
FROM staging_projects;

row_rec get_rows%ROWTYPE;
nb_countries number:=0;
country VARCHAR2(4);
BEGIN
OPEN get_rows;
LOOP
  FETCH get_rows INTO row_rec;
  EXIT WHEN get_rows%NOTFOUND;
  SELECT regexp_count(row_rec.participantcountries, ';') INTO nb_countries
  FROM staging_projects
  WHERE p_id=row_rec.p_id;
  IF (row_rec.participantcountries  IS NULL) THEN
    nb_countries:=0;  -- if the field is null set counter to zero 
  ELSE
    nb_countries:=nb_countries+1; -- nb of delimiters so +1 --> number of items
  END IF;
  WHILE (nb_countries >0) LOOP -- loop and get single country at current counter position
      SELECT (regexp_substr(PARTICIPANTCOUNTRIES,'[^;]+', 1, nb_countries)) INTO country
      FROM (SELECT * FROM staging_projects WHERE p_id=row_rec.p_id)
      WHERE participantcountries IS NOT NULL;
      nb_countries:=nb_countries-1;                     
      INSERT INTO project_countries(proj_id, country_code) VALUES(row_rec.p_id, country);
  END LOOP;
 END LOOP;

 CLOSE get_rows;

 END split_countries;
```

This works fine but it seems like an overly complicated solution for the problem at hand.